# Is there a way to turn Jenkins job into a Jenkins DSL script automatically?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I use [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to generate my Jenkins builds. But sometimes I make small changes to the build in Jenkins and I want to port those changes back to my DSL script automatically. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way to generate a Job DSL script for an existing job. This has been reported in the Jenkins issue tracker as [JENKINS-16360](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16360) some time ago and someone even offered a [bounty](https://freedomsponsors.org/issue/622/print-dsl-formatted-configxml-for-an-existing-job), but AFAIK no one is working on the issue.